# Website is not showing up in google search results, even though it is indexed

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, google-search-site-name

My (NSFW) website is indexed by Google, I can see it in the Google Search Console, and according to that, everything is fine, I have good usability and no issues.

**I had pretty good results right after launching it**, but at some point something strange happened. I had to verify my domain ownership again, and since then **I cannot see my site in the search results any more**. *Not even for very specific keywords*, not even on the last page of Google search.  Although, as I mentioned, I can see the domain in the search console, and it is verified.

When I search for the site url specifically, I can see the result, but seems like Google ignores my title and description meta tags and auto-generates them.

Additional context:

- I am hosting my site on Heroku. I had issues because Google realized the content are duplicated (was visible on my domain and on the *.herokuapp.com domain as well). I fixed that issue more than a week ago(using "canonical" meta tag and permanent redirect to my domain), and the fix was approved by Google.
- I use Cloudflare and the DNS setup works, I redirect every request from [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) to mysite.com and all http request to the secure https
- I have a valid sitemap.xml and robots.txt
- Tried a few SEO tools and all of them said I have good SEO
- I had the same meta and description tag on few of my pages but correted that as well almost a week ago
- According to the search console I do not have any penalty

I feel like I did everything, but Google still does not show my site in the search results. I am really desperate at this point.

**My questions are: What can be the issue with the indexing? What can I do to get back the same indexing as before?**

Answer (score 2):

It does look weird. Google makes up its own mind about what to display.  Observations

- your `og:description` and `twitter:description` do not match with `description`.  But Google does not use those.
- `title`, `H1` and `description` don't have much relevance with each other (in terms of the number of words).
- `H1` and `title` are too short, in my opinion.
- It looks like your site is new.  It is possible that you originally had the same description on all the pages.  So, request to `reindex the pages`

Note that for new sites, it can take months to get indexed properly.

There's a discussion on [another Webmaster post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/88329/123687)